# Is there a bitbucket api for getting detailed app password permissions?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

Is it possible to get exact / detailed permissions associated with a a bitbucket app password/token? (see screenshot)
[image]

We have the following APIs to get user permissions in repository, and workspace permissions.

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repository}/permissions-config/users/{username}`
and 
`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user/permissions/workspaces`

But they're more "high level"(ex: does the user have an admin account).